# i updated aws amplify from v5 to v6, but unable to find few changes in v6

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Amplify as AmplifyConfig } from 'aws-amplify'; // Import Amplify as AmplifyConfig
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify/api';
import {listBatches} from './graphql/queries'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

AmplifyConfig.configure(awsconfig); // Use AmplifyConfig instead of Amplify

const AllBatches = () => {
  const [batch, setBatch] = useState([]);

  useEffect (() => {
    fetchBatch();
  },[])

 const fetchBatch = async() => {
  try{
    const batchData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listBatches));
    const batchList = batchData.data.listBatches.items;
    console.log('batch list',batchList);
    setBatch(batchList)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error on fetching batch', error);
  }
 }

enter image description here, i provided code snippet, what are changes i has to make.
```

Need to update my code from aws amplify v5 to v6, my code was in aws amplify v5, unabke to find the changes are made in v6 for API  and need necessary to make in the code